# How to remove/hide column wise repetitive cell text

Tags: angular, typescript, grid, syncfusion

I have a syncfusion grid which has column level repetitive data but i don't want to show the repeated data, except for the first occurrence. So it will give me a tree kind of view, please refer below image.

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaMQG.png)

How can i achieve it?

Comment: What does your data structure look like?

Comment: @robbieAreBest it will be flat data as below

Comment: [
            {department: 'Dept 1',class: 'Class 1',subClass: 'Subclass1'},
            {department: 'Dept 1',class: 'Class 1',subClass: 'Subclass2'},
            {department: 'Dept 1',class: 'Class 2',subClass: 'Subclass3'},
            {department: 'Dept 1',class: 'Class 2',subClass: 'Subclass4'}
          ]

Answer (score 0):

The Syncfusion EJ2 Grid renders the underlying data including the duplicate field values in the defined columns by default. If you need to empty the duplicate cells, then it would have to be done in the UI level by dynamically taking each column value and comparing it with the other values in the current view and removing it if duplicate. Now if paging is enabled(default page size is ‘12’) and there are around 10 columns, then this comparison loop has to be done for around 12 * 10 = 120 times. And the loop will increase based on the increase of page size and total columns. This will cause performance degradation when large amount of data and fields are present.

So to avoid this if you need to remove duplicate values, then we suggest you to remove/empty it directly in the data source and bind it to the Grid.